# Filename with dates. need to store file with the filename of dates of having last month of the year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, python-datetime

Hi i have tried but not able to get the logic.
I have a folder with many files (csv's) and they are all in the format of ranging from oct2020 to sept2021. But some files have missing months data as well. the format of the filename is

```
eg: ['20201117_KR_App Download - NBA Draft.csv',
 '20210130_KR_Get Out The Vote #2_International.csv',
 '20210204_KR_Get Out The Vote #4_International.csv',
 '20210430_KR_iLP Newsletter #1_Active Subs.csv',
 '20210514_KR_Last Weekend 15 Games_Email_MAN_Promo_ILP_ACQ_PRO_Global_EN.csv',
 '20210605_KR_Playoffs2ndRdGm1_Email_MAN_Offer_ILP_ACQ_PRO_Global_EN.csv',
 '20210706_KR_Playoffs4thRdGm1_Email_MAN_Tune-in_ILP_RET_SUBS_Global_EN.csv']
```

the number in the filename is the date so 20201117 means 2020-11-17 in the format %y%m%d. I want to retrieve the file with the last month of year of 2020 in one dataframe and last month of 2021 in other dataframe present in a folder. how we can achieve this in python.

what i did is retrived all the files in the folder

```
'''
          country='SouthKorea'
          files = pd.Series(os.listdir('../input/' + country))
          # second, iterate over dates
          for date in pd.date_range('2020-10-01', '2021-09-30', freq='MS').strftime('%Y%m%d'):
              for file_name in files[files.str.contains(date)]:
                  print(file_name)
'''
```

please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all the files that start with a specific year, and since it's in the form of YYYMMDD, just get the max from that list:

```
files = ['20201117_KR_App Download - NBA Draft.csv',
 '20210130_KR_Get Out The Vote #2_International.csv',
 '20210204_KR_Get Out The Vote #4_International.csv',
 '20210430_KR_iLP Newsletter #1_Active Subs.csv',
 '20210514_KR_Last Weekend 15 Games_Email_MAN_Promo_ILP_ACQ_PRO_Global_EN.csv',
 '20210605_KR_Playoffs2ndRdGm1_Email_MAN_Offer_ILP_ACQ_PRO_Global_EN.csv',
 '20210706_KR_Playoffs4thRdGm1_Email_MAN_Tune-in_ILP_RET_SUBS_Global_EN.csv']



years = ['2020','2021']
for year in years:
    # Get all files that start with year
    result = max([i for i in files if i.startswith(year)])
    print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
20201117_KR_App Download - NBA Draft.csv
20210706_KR_Playoffs4thRdGm1_Email_MAN_Tune-in_ILP_RET_SUBS_Global_EN.csv
```